# Bug in my Flash Action Script 3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I am working on a "simple" flash project. .   The flash element has 2 buttons, each with text and changing images.  The text and images to be displayed are read from XML files.   This project will be used as default page for Kiosks at various locations. I will be passing the kiosk location to the SWF file via flashVars.  This will enable the kiosk to pull location specific text and images.  I am NOT a flash developer but was given this project because no one else wanted it or knew anything about AS3.  I have found many great examples on stackOverflow and google that I used to write this project.

My problem is that when you hover over the button, the images in rotation blank out.

Originally both buttons where dynamic from the XML file, and both where blanking out the images.  In troubleshooting I hard coded the left button and the images no longer blanked out.  I am not sure if the bug in the timeline or the as3 code. The fact that hard coding the xml file location 'fixes' the issue does not make sense to me when it in fact is reading the dynmic xml file to show the images to start with.

I have put this project on my personal site so anyone wanting to help can view and access the files.

To view: http://minerb.com/kiosk/as3.cfm

Both sides hardcoded path to xml file and it works: http://minerb.com/kiosk/as4.cfm

To access files: http://minerb.com/kiosk/index.cfm

Code snip from working hard coded xml file location(Option1SlideShow lines 21-30):

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getMinutes();





my_xml_loader.load(new URLRequest("assets/default/content.xml?"+n));
```

Code snip from NON working dynamic xml file location(dyanmic slidedhow lines 21-30):
:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getMinutes();
// start dynamic content.xml 
var option2Loc:String;
option2Loc = loaderInfo.parameters.option2Loc+"content.xml?"+n;
// end dynamic content.xml

my_xml_loader.load(new URLRequest(option2Loc));
```

**Entire AS3 code that loads the images from XML File**

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;

var my_speed:Number;
var my_total:Number;
var my_images:XMLList;

var my_loaders_array:Array = [];
var my_success_counter:Number = 0;
var my_playback_counter:Number = 0;

var my_slideshow:Sprite = new Sprite();
var my_image_slides:Sprite = new Sprite(); 

var my_timer:Timer;
var my_prev_tween:Tween; 

var my_xml_loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

//start test bits
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getMinutes();
// start dynamic content.xml 
    var option2Loc:String;
    option2Loc = loaderInfo.parameters.option2Loc+"content.xml?"+n;
// end dynamic content.xml

   my_xml_loader.load(new URLRequest(option2Loc));
//end test bits

my_xml_loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);





function processXML (e:Event):void{
    var my_xml:XML = new XML(e.target.data); 
    my_speed=my_xml.button.images.@SPEED;
    my_images=my_xml.button.images.IMAGE;
    my_total=my_images.length();    

    loadImages();
}

function loadImages():void{
    for (var i:Number = 0; i < my_total; i++){
        var my_url:String = my_images[i].@URL;
        var my_loader:Loader = new Loader();
        my_loader.load(new URLRequest(my_url));
        my_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
        my_loaders_array.push(my_loader); 
    }
}

function onComplete(e:Event):void{
    my_success_counter++;
    if (my_success_counter == my_total){
        startShow();
    }

}      

function startShow():void{
    addChild(my_slideshow);
    my_slideshow.addChild(my_image_slides);

    setChildIndex(my_slideshow,0);

nextImage();

    my_timer = new Timer(my_speed*1000);
    my_timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener);
    my_timer.start();


}

function nextImage():void{
    var my_image:Loader = Loader(my_loaders_array[my_playback_counter]);
    my_image_slides.addChild(my_image);
    //my_image.x = (stage.stageWidth - my_image.width)/2;
    //my_image.y = (stage.stageHeight - my_image.height)/2;


    if (my_image.width == my_image.height) {
        my_image.width = 305;
        my_image.height = 305;
    }   else if( my_image.width > my_image.height ) {
            var newWidth = (my_image.width *(305 / my_image.height));
            my_image.height = 305;  
            my_image.width = newWidth;
    }   else if( my_image.width < my_image.height ) {
            var newHeight = (my_image.height *(305 / my_image.width));
            my_image.width = 305;   
            my_image.height = newHeight;

    }

    my_image.x = 80;
    my_image.y = -140;


    new Tween(my_image,"alpha",Strong.easeOut,0,1,1,true); 



}     

function timerListener (e:TimerEvent):void{
    hidePrev();

    my_playback_counter++;
    if (my_playback_counter == my_total){
        my_playback_counter =0;
    }

nextImage();

} 

function hidePrev():void{
var my_image:Loader=Loader(my_image_slides.getChildAt(0));
my_prev_tween = new Tween(my_image,"alpha",Strong.easeOut,1,0,1,true);
my_prev_tween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, onFadeOut)

new Tween(my_image,"alpha",Strong.easeOut,1,0,1,true);

} 

function onFadeOut(e:TweenEvent):void{
my_image_slides.removeChildAt(0);

}
```

**End AS3 code for loading images**

** Entire AS3 code for loading dynmic text from XMl File **

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;
// start dynamic content.xml 

var option2Loc:String;
option2Loc = loaderInfo.parameters.option2Loc;

// end dynamic content.xml
var xmlData:XML = new XML();
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getMinutes();

var theURL_ur:URLRequest = new URLRequest(option2Loc+"content.xml?"+n);
var loader_ul:URLLoader = new URLLoader(theURL_ur);
loader_ul.addEventListener("complete", fileLoaded);

function fileLoaded(e:Event):void
{
xmlData = XML(loader_ul.data);
option2Text.text = xmlData.button.text;

}
```

** End code for loading text **

Comment: None of the code  you posted has anything to do with rollover behavior.

Comment: right.. but, to start with both buttons had the same code as the second snip, and both would blank out the images on rollover.  I hard coded the xml location on the left side button and it stopped blanking out the images.  other than that, the code top to bottom is identical other than specific variable names.    I will post the entire AS3 code.

Comment: the ONLY thing I've changed in the version that 'works' the version that does not work, is hard coding the path to the XML file....   This is the version that has the path passed via flashVars, it loads the images but when you mouse over the disappear http://minerb.com/kiosk/as3.cfm  if I hard code the path to the xml file it works with the mouseover... http://minerb.com/kiosk/as4.cfm   why would that affect mouseover? you would think the images would fail to load initially if there was a problem.

Comment: Where did you write this code (on a frame, on a symbol, in an as file)? I'm suspecting loaderInfo does not match stage.loaderInfo. Do you get any error in the console? Can you trace loaderInfo, loaderInfo.parameters and loaderInfo.parameters.option2Loc?